# nodejs http listener argument must be a function

Tags: node.js

Attempting to pass a responseHandler from a require rather than having it in the same file but getting error listener argument must be a function. console.log the require return, returns a function, so I don't see the issue?

```
var responseHandler = require("./downloader.js");
log(responseHandler); // Logs [Functions: responseHandler)
request = https.get(fileUrl, responseHandler); // Error "listener" argument must be a function (according to the log line above, it is!?)
```

If I swap out line 1 for the contents of downloader.js all works fine...

Content of downloader.js is just

```
var responseHandler = function(response){
    // some code to process response.statusCode
    response.on('data',function(chunk){//stuff});
    response.on('error',function(e){//stuff});
    response.on('end',function(e){//stuff});
}
exports.responseHandler = responseHandler;
```

I would like to keep the main file clean and small and have this working as a require, ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to only export the function you can do it with:

```
module.exports = responseHandler;
```

Then the imported value will be the function rather than an object with a function value:

```
var responseHandler = require("./downloader.js");
```

Answer (score 1):

You will need to try doing:

```
request = https.get(fileUrl, responseHandler.responseHandler);
```

You're exporting an object that has a function called responseHandler, so you need to call it directly

Comment: This seems more correct ans as what if there are multiple functions in `.js` file present you cant just export a single function then.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can export only function without name

```
module.exports = (response)=> {
    // some code to process response.statusCode
    response.on('data',function(chunk){//stuff});
    response.on('error',function(e){//stuff});
    response.on('end',function(e){//stuff});
}
```